# PTIJ: If Haman would have fallen with no one around to hear him fall, would that still have made a sound?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Esther 7:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.7.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) writes:

> והמלך שב מגנת הביתן אל־בית משתה היין והמן נפל על־המטה אשר אסתר עליה ויאמר המלך הגם לכבוש את־המלכה עמי בבית הדבר יצא מפי המלך ופני המן חפו
>
> When the king returned from the palace garden to the banquet room, Haman fell on the couch on which Esther reclined. “Does he mean,” cried the king, “to ravish the queen in my own palace?” No sooner did these words leave the king’s lips than Haman’s face was covered.

The Megillah makes it clear that Achashverosh was in the room when Haman fell, but I can't help but wonder:

If Haman would have fallen with no one around to hear him fall, would that still have made a sound?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is actually an age old debate, as we learn in Bereishis 3:11

> המן העץ
>
> Haman is a tree

And therefore, the question you are really asking is, if a tree falls and there is no one around to hear it, does it make a sound? That question is far beyond the scope of this forum to address fully.

Comment: Beyond the scope of Mi Yodeya? [Heaven forfend.](/q/55273/170)

Answer (score 0):

No one would know the definitive answer to this either way, despite daily inquiries on the matter.

Numerous people say פרשת המן - the section describing Haman's affair. (one definition of *parsha* is "affair"). There's nothing in there that describes what happened to Haman after he fell on the bed. I can understand why there is that omission. He was there with Esther, so it was a private affair.